# Fill Out The Gaps Between Two Times With PHP

Tags: php, loops

I've got to write a loop that should start and end between two times.  I know there are many ways to skin this cat, but I'd like to see a real programmers approach to this function.

Essentially I have Wednesday, for instance, that opens at 6:00pm and closes at 10:30pm.

I'm looking to write a loop that will give me a table with all of the times in between those two in 15 minute intervals.

So, I basically want to build a one column table where each row is

```
6:00pm
6:15pm
7:15pm
```

etc...

My two variables to feed this function will be the open time and the close time.
Now don't accuse me of "write my code for me" posting.  I'll happily give you my hacked solution on request, I'd just like to see how someone with real experience would create this function.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$start = new DateTime("2011-08-18 18:00:00");
$end = new DateTime("2011-08-18 22:30:00");
$current = clone $start;
while ($current <= $end) {
    echo $current->format("g:ia"), "\n";
    $current->modify("+15 minutes");
}
```

Try it on Codepad: http://codepad.org/JwBDOQQE

Comment: It's a thing of beauty. Thank you :) (I gotta wait 6 more minutes to mark you as correct, but, it's coming)

Comment: +1 - Although isn't the start variable and clone redundant? http://codepad.org/7LgqD2Mx

Comment: Also your date is for thursday, while the question asks for Wednesday. ;D

Answer (score 4):

PHP 5.3 introduced a class precisely for this purpose, [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/dateperiod).

```
$start    = new DateTime("6:00pm");
$end      = new DateTime("10:30pm");
$interval = new DateInterval('PT15M');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $time) {
    echo $time->format('g:ia'), PHP_EOL;
}

echo $end->format('g:ia'); // end time is not part of the period
```

Comment: @Gerry, note the "for instance" following the mention of Wednesday. It's trivial to change the start/end dates/times as appropriate.

Comment: I did note it, I'm just teasing.

Comment: @Gerry, it's hard to tell sometimes… people on here can be so pernickity! :-)

Comment: Heh, yeah well the output is identical no matter what day you use. But I hear ya. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = strtotime('2011-08-11 18:00:00');

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
   echo date('g:ia', $start + ($i * (15 * 60))), '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I have seen you giving lovely anwsers (not this one) why 20? where do it cames from?

Comment: Just some random ending value. In this case, it'll output 20 :15minute intervals.

Comment: but not acomplish the request

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) functions and [increase the time by 15 minutes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) every loop-turn as long as the current time is lower then the end-time.

EDIT: as user576875 has posted

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_date = '2019-07-30 08:00:00';
$end_date = '2019-09-31 08:00:00';
while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    echo "$start_date<br>";


    $start_date = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 hours", strtotime($start_date)));
}
```